# Add custom generator in addition to default rails generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What I need is to add some translations to i18n on scaffold generating. I'd like to know: is there possibility to force *rails g scaffold* to invoke my own generator in addition to defaults?

If not, how can I invoke default Rails generators (e.g. *active_record*) in my generator?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the doc here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#generate), you can use `generate` from your generator to invoke another generator.

```
generate a_generator_name, args_as_string
```

---

```
class FooGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
  argument :attributes, :type => :array

  def call
    do_your_stuff
    run_scaffold
  end

  private

  def do_your_stuff
  end

  def run_scaffold
    generate 'scaffold', attributes.join(' ')
  end
end
```

Comment: I know I can use my own generator separately, but I want it to invokes automatically on _rails g scaffold ModelName_ invoking.

Comment: the only way would be to monkey patch the rails generator which is not recommended. Create your own and invoke the Rails one, as you already thought about

Comment: It's a pity, but I don't know how to invoke rails generators inside my generators.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you mean this method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Generators/Actions.html#method-i-generate
It acts like calling _rails g smth_ in console. But I need to accessing rails builtin generators like _active\_record_, which creates models and migrations. Is it possible?

Comment: yes, since you desire to patch `scaffold`, you'd do: `generate 'scaffold', args_as_string`

Comment: Thanks, now I see you. One last question: how can I get all options passed to generator?